# WSO2 BAM error on running hive script "am_stats_analyzer_163" cassandra

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, hive, wso2, wso2-bam

I run APIM and BAM on 2 different virtual machines, with an external Cassandra on BAM.

I have an ***"Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask"*** error when executing a hive script (am_stats_analyzer_163)

This is the full error trace:

```
TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-03-18 12:34:07,948] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Ended Job = job_local_0001 with errors {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-03-18 12:34:07,950] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Error during job, obtaining debugging information... {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-03-18 12:34:08,041] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  Execution failed with exit status: 2 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-03-18 12:34:08,042] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  Obtaining error information {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-03-18 12:34:08,042] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -
Task failed!
Task ID:
  Stage-0

Logs:
 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-03-18 12:34:08,042] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task} -  /opt/wso2bam-2.4.0/repository/logs//wso2carbon.log {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-03-18 12:34:08,042] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Execution failed with exit status: 2 {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-03-18 12:34:08,042] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -  FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-03-18 12:34:08,044] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl} -  Error while executing Hive script.
Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl}
java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.executeQuery(HiveStatement.java:189)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.executeHiveQuery(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:569)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:282)
    at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:189)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
TID: [0] [BAM] [2014-03-18 12:34:08,044] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Error while executing script : am_stats_analyzer_163 {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.exception.HiveExecutionException: Error while executing Hive script.Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl.execute(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:115)
org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask.execute(HiveScriptExecutorTask.java:60)
    at     org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.TaskQuartzJobAdapter.execute(TaskQuartzJobAdapter.java:67)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

The username and passwords that I use for cassandra are the default ones (admin/admin), and they are defined as such in **[BAM_HOME]/repository/conf/etc/cassandra-auth.xml** and in **[BAM_HOME]/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml**

Do you know what can be the issue?

Eternal MySQL datasource config:

```
<datasource>
            <name>WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for getting statistics to API Manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://GCEP-IDS:3306/APIMGTSTATS_DB</url>
                <username>ldapadmin</username>
                <password>ldapadmin</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <minIdle>5</minIdle>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
     </datasource>
```

**api-manager.xml** configuration:

```
 <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <PublisherClass>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher</PublisherClass>
    <ThriftPort>7611</ThriftPort>

    <BAMServerURL>tcp://135.238.115.232:7611</BAMServerURL>
    <BAMUsername>admin</BAMUsername>
    <BAMPassword>admin</BAMPassword>
    <DataSourceName>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</DataSourceName>
```

Also the tables were created inside the MySQL DB:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| APIMGTSTATS_DB     |
| mysql              |
| regdb              |
| test               |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> use APIMGTSTATS_DB
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_APIMGTSTATS_DB  |
+---------------------------+
| API_REQUEST_SUMMARY       |
| API_RESPONSE_SUMMARY      |
| API_VERSION_USAGE_SUMMARY |
+---------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from API_REQUEST_SUMMARY;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from API_RESPONSE_SUMMARY;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from API_VERSION_USAGE_SUMMARY;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> \q
Bye
[root@GCEP-IDS ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have configured api-manager.xml with correct BAMServerURL and ThriftPort, which is placed in /repository/conf/api-manager.xml

```
<!-- Enable/Disable the API usage tracker. -->
<Enabled>true</Enabled>  
    <PublisherClass>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageDataBridgeDataPublisher</PublisherClass>
    <ThriftPort>7612</ThriftPort>
    <BAMServerURL>tcp://localhost:7612/</BAMServerURL>
    <BAMUsername>admin</BAMUsername>
    <BAMPassword>admin</BAMPassword>
    <!-- JNDI name of the data source to be used for getting BAM statistics. This data source should
        be defined in the master-datasources.xml file in conf/datasources directory. -->
    <DataSourceName>jdbc/WSO2AM_STATS_DB</DataSourceName>

</APIUsageTracking>
```

Comment: Hi poohdedoo, the api-manager.xml seems to be configured correctly (pls see configuration in main question)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a problem with RDBMS related Hive query due to the SQL exception. Please recheck whether the Hive script runs when "insert overwrite ..." queries are removed. If that is the case recheck that part of script. Before re-executing the query manually drop the RDBMS table (e.g. Using a H2 database client) and add "drop table ..." like queries on top of the Hive script to clean RDBMS wrapped Hive tables.

Comment: Hi Maninda, you were right regarding "insert overwrite" part, if i remove them it works. As for the H2 part, i am using an external MySQL database on another wirtual machine (IDS WM). In master datasources the datasource is configured the same as WSO2_CARBON_DB datasource, but with another db. the db was created previously and rights access has been granted to the user (see below datasource configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Try set hostName to 0.0.0.0 in data-bridge-config.xml:

```
<thriftDataReceiver>
    <hostName>0.0.0.0</hostName>
        <port>7611</port>
        <securePort>7711</securePort>
</thriftDataReceiver>
```

and set rpc_address: 0.0.0.0 in cassandra.yaml.

The error was related to incorrect host/port.